# Gerrit server hook to validate the commit message

Tags: gerrit

I'm using `Gerrit-2.16.17` as a code review tool and need to configure server side hooks to validate the commit message when a commit is received by Gerrit for code review to `(refs/for/branch)`.

We need to follow the below `custom commit message`. If suppose the below contents are not present in our commit message. Gerrit automatically need to be rejected before a review request is gets created.

```
Feature Ver: 
Bug-ID: 
Task:
Test result:
```

According to this [Document](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/hooks.md#commit_received) to validate incoming commits, On the server side `$GERRIT_SITE/hooks/commit-received` custom hook needs to be created.  Is there any pre-script is available to validate our commit message? Need help to configure/enforce this hook on server side.

Comment: `commit-received` is a *Gerrit* hook, not a Git hook. This has nothing to do with Git itself.

Comment: The logic you are after is custom for your specific use case, hence I doubt you will find a script that does exactly what you mean. The documentation you have linked states: `If the hook exits with non-zero return code the push will be rejected.` That means you will have to write a script (bash/python/perl,...) to implement exactly your custom logic and return `0` when the push has to be accepted and `non-zero` otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example of `commit-received` hook:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $@

echo Project: $2
echo Refname: $4
echo Uploader: $6
echo Uploader-username: $8

if [[ $2 = "test" ]]
then
  exit 0
else
  exit -1
fi
```

Following an example of successful push on the `test` repository:

```
➜  test git:(master) git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 290 bytes | 290.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, updated: 1, done
remote: commit b2f0e7d: --project test --refname refs/heads/master --uploader Administrator <admin@example.com> --uploader-username admin --oldrev 9d4768e749448cbf10c9e4a1297f4ac206ea9e84 --newrev b2f0e7d920f35719cfa4a9bb5c5d2d54d6dad768 --cmdref refs/for/master
remote: Project: test
remote: Refname: refs/heads/master
remote: Uploader: Administrator <admin@example.com>
remote: Uploader-username: admin
remote:
remote: SUCCESS
remote:
remote:   http://localhost:8080/c/test/+/41 Testina
remote:
To ssh://localhost:29418/test
 * [new reference]   HEAD -> refs/for/master
```

And a failing push on the `shouldfail` repository:

```
➜  shouldfail git:(master) git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 274 bytes | 274.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
To ssh://localhost:29418/shouldfail
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (commit 9addd6c: --project shouldfail --refname refs/heads/master --uploader Administrator <admin@example.com> --uploader-username admin --oldrev 6fcf316d435687e9138f4d63e228bdeafd40daae --newrev 9addd6c796fce09d187d90251b32b152530e8a4b --cmdref refs/for/master
Project: shouldfail
Refname: refs/heads/master
Uploader: Administrator <admin@example.com>
Uploader-username: admin)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://localhost:29418/shouldfail'
```

I wrote the example in bash, but you can use any scripting language.

Note the everything you will print in the hook server-side, will b displayed client-side.

Comment: everything you will print in the hook server-side, will b displayed client-side. it's very useful . thank you barbasa.